# Bind DataGrid Column to ViewModel Property

Tags: silverlight

If I have the following DataGrid, how would I go about binding the Visibility of the TemplateColumn to a property on my ViewModel?  The code I have here is based on a recommendation from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825454/silverlight-mvvm-binding-viewmodel-property-to-datagrid-column)  but no luck.

```
            <sdk:DataGrid Visibility="{Binding GridVisible}" DataContext="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BookSource}" x:Name="bookGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.GridImgColumnVisible, ElementName=bookGrid}">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=SmallImgURI}"></Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"  Width="*"  Binding="{Binding CurrentBook.Title}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Published" Width="150"  Binding="{Binding CurrentBook.Published, StringFormat=d}" />
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
```

EDIT - I've also tried:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.GridImgColumnVisible, ElementName=root}">
```

and I've also added a button to my actual control, and bound its visibility to this property without difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved in WPF, but Silverlight DataGrid is different. Visibility property isn't dependency property (you can't perform binding), Columns aren't belong to VisualTree and don't inherit DataContext.

Use code-behind, something like this:

```
var model = (MyViewModel)this.DataContext;
model.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => 
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "GridImgColumnVisible")
        this.UpdateGridColumnVisibility(model.GridImgColumnVisible);
};

public void UpdateGridColumnVisibility(Visibility imageVisibility)
{
    var imgColumn = bookGrid.Columns.Cast<DataGridColumn>().FirstOrDefault(c => ((string)c.GetValue(Panel.NameProperty)) == "imgColumn");
    if(imgColumn != null)
        imgColumn.Visibility = imageVisibility;
}
```

And add the name to the column:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="imgColumn">
```